# How to disable on cloudinary-react video component the download button

Tags: reactjs, cloudinary

I need to disable the download button from the cloudinary-react Video component. 
The [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/react_video_manipulation) page mentions nothing about the video download button customization and also on [github clowdinary-react](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-react) I was not able to find related documentation.

How do disable the download button form the cloudinary-react Video component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this working using this:

```
<Video
    cloudName={myCloudName}
    publicId={videoId}
    autoPlay={true}
    controls={true}
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    disablePictureInPicture
    controlsList="nodownload"
  />
```

More info about how to customize the player can be located at: [HTMLMediaElement controlsList Sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media/controlslist.html)